# How open a specific uitabbarcontroller from AppDelegate with push notifications?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, appdelegate

I'm using push notifications on my app. So, when I receive a notification and touch it, I want go to another `UITabbarcontroller`, but when I doing it the app only show the `UINavigationbar` and don't the `UITabbarcontroller`. This a screenshot -->

[image]

And this my code.

```
         let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequestDriverViewController") as! RequestDriverViewController

         let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

         self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
         self.window?.rootViewController = nc
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Please read the section "Responding to Notifications and Events" in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

Comment: You need to provide lore details about your navigation controller / tab bar controller hierarchy. There's usually a sibfly tab bar controller, which in turn contains several navigation controllers, so the usual approach is to switch to the desired tab, possibly popping unwanted view controllers on the way, but your specific situation may be quite different...

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for yours comments, really were many helpful, i have many work and thus i couldn't see that i should access to UItabbarcontroller identifier first before to UIViewcontroller. So this the code that i used for to solve my question:

let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarIdentifier") as! UITabBarController
            
            
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Many thanks

Comment: @matt Thak for your answer, really were helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarIdentifier") as! UITabBarController

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: If the tab bar controller already exists, you most probably shouldn't instantiate it again, you should simply retrieve it and make any needed changes to it (change the currently active tab for instance)

Comment: @jcaron Then, if the app is in background? ...How i retrieve it ? For this i think that is necessary creat a instance it, however i can do a "If" that verify to if app is in background or no. If yes, then instantiate, if Not, then retrieve it.

However, ¿How i can retrieve this UItabBarController?

Comment: Use your windows's `rootViewController`. Check that it's not nil and that it's an instance of an `UITabBarController`, then use it.